# unresolved external with static variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static, include, double

I have a class called Pub which has the following header:

```
#pragma once



class Pub
{

public:
    static double X_FACTOR;
    static double Y_FACTOR;
    static const int INIT_SCREEN_WIDTH=500;
    static const int INIT_SCREEN_HEIGHT=550;


    Pub(void);
    ~Pub(void);
};
```

I am trying to set the variable Y_FACTOR in main.cpp with the following:

```
Pub::Y_FACTOR=1.0;
```

and yes Pub.h is included properly which can be demonstrated as I can access INIT_SCREEN_WIDTH and INIT_SCREEN_HEIGHT
However when I do this I get the following error:

> Error 6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static
>   double Pub::Y_FACTOR"
>   (?Y_FACTOR@Pub@@2NA)  C:\Users\Pedro-Estevan-Juarez\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Project2\Project2\main.obj  Project2 Error  7   error
>   LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Pedro-Estevan-Juarez\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe  1   1   Project2

I suspect this is something syntax wise, can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code inside the class definition is just a declaration. You need to add definition of the static variable in a cpp file. 
Add this in your cpp file and in file scope before any function using it.

```
double Pub::Y_FACTOR;
```

Comment: Yes that worked, however why is this? Seems really foreign to me to have to do this?

Comment: Yes that is one thing not intuitive in C++. C++ standard define it this way. And if standard define it as definition, then when this header file include in multiple cpp, it will voliate ODR.